# css changes according to page - not different files

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Is there a way to change the CSS style, according to what page the users clicks? And not load different CSS files every time, to do this?

I have a web mapping site, so in small devices I want to do `display : none` for the header, so the map's div will appear bigger. I will use media queries for this, but the header also changes in all the other pages. I want it to change only in the map's page.

How can I do this? It would be great if there is a method that you dont have to load different CSS files. Is it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The structure of my files is like

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 include_once('header.php');

//rest of the code of the file starts here....
```

where `header.php` contains header, menu bar, metadata.

So I cannot just give an id to the header, cause it will still be the same id visible from all the pages

Thanks again

Comment: One common way of having page-specific styles is to give the `body` or `html` element a unique id per page – and then simply use that id in your CSS selectors to define different styles for different pages.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the anser. Interesting, but, I dont think it will help me. I forgot to mention about the structure of my files. I edited the question.

Comment: Of course you can do that – by simply setting a variable before the include and depending on that echoing the id for body.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for the late anser. I'm not sure I got what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: `pageId='foo'; include 'header.php';` – and then in that script you just output the content of the variable as id attribute value for the `body` element …

Answer (score 0):

If your page is static one and you need to make only one change, just create a `class` with `display:none;` and apply the same to the header without affecting any other page or page elements.

This way, your header also gets hidden and your purpose also gets resolved.

Other way would be to add an `id` to your `<body>` and by using parent child CSS selector, hiding your header subsequently for those pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the anser. Interesting, but, I dont think it will help me. I forgot to mention about the structure of my files. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

ou can check your URL through JavaScript and add style for specific element

example

```
 if (window.location.href.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("map") != -1) { // If url contains maps
            document.getElementById("p2").style.display="none";
        }
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Will check and let you know.